# no declaration can be found for element 'constructor-arg'

Tags: mule, mule-studio

The error when running:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 30; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'constructor-arg'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
```

The source:

```
<spring:bean id="HandlerA_id" name="HandlerA" class="Handler"> 
            <constructor-arg> 
                <ref bean="BeanA"></ref>  
            </constructor-arg>  
        </spring:bean>
```

The editor recognizes the constructor-arg tag and gives a summary upon roll-over.
In the config file, xsi:schemaLocation value contains (among others):

```
"...http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd..."
```

If you examine the xsd at that URL, you can see that the constructor-arg tag is valid for group beanElements which is one of the complex types allowed in 'bean'

Does the runtime not properly validate XML under some conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the `spring:` prefix in the tag. Same for the ref tag.